# ¿Cómo generar un organigrama con Org chart?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, php8

Estoy intentando crear un organigrama jerárquico a partir de un archivo php que realiza dos consultas a una base de datos sql server, luego estas dos consultas se imprimen en un solo resultado para luego capturarlos con ajax desde una página web html o php y con estos resultados generar un organigrama jerárquico, en el script se reciben tres parámetros **parentId, memberId, otherInfo** que son los alias de las consultas con estas consultas se generan los niveles y subniveles con javascript estoy usando **jquery.orgchart.js** para cargar los niveles ¿Mi pregunta es cómo puedo generar los niveles y subniveles en **javascript** sin depender de estas tres variables parentId,memberId, otherInfo ya que los niveles se generan a partir de estos alias, cómo por ejemplo puedo hacer que la segunda consuta pueda automáticamente ingresar al nivel dos y la tercera en el nivel 3 y asi sucesivamente

```html
<?php

$serverName = "server";
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "tree", "UID" => "SA", "PWD" => "1234", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);


$sql = "select iddirector as memberId, idsuperior as parentId  ,nombres as otherInfo from directores";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$datos = [];
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $datos[] = $row;
}

if (isset($row)) {
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $json = json_encode(array('code' => 200, 'status' => 'ok', 'message' => 'Success SELECT', 'data' => $datos), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

$sql1 = "select iduser as  parentId  ,nompais as otherInfo from alumnos";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1);

$datos1 = [];
while ($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $datos1[] = $row1;
}

if (isset($row1)) {
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $json1 = json_encode(array('code' => 200, 'status' => 'ok', 'message' => 'Success SELECT', 'data' => $datos1), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt1);


$resultado = array_merge($datos,$datos1);
echo json_encode($resultado);

?>
```

Este es mi archivo html en donde se genera en organigrama con javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>


  <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.orgchart.css" />
  <script src="jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
      var members;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'load4.php',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
             
          members = $.parseJSON(data)
    
   
        }
      })
      
      for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        
        var member = members[i];
        var parentId = member.parentId;
       console.log(parentId);
        if (parentId === "true") {
      console.log("hola");
        }
        if (i== 0) {
                                      
         $("#chart-container2").append("<li id=" + member.memberId + ">" + member.otherInfo + "</li>")
        } else {

          if ($('#pr_' + member.parentId).length <= 0) {
            $('#' + member.parentId).append("<ul id='pr_" + member.parentId + "'><li id=" + member.memberId + ">" + member.otherInfo + "</li></ul>")
           
          }
         
          else {
            $('#pr_' + member.parentId).append("<li id=" + member.memberId + ">" + member.otherInfo + "</li>")
          }   if ($('#pr_' + member.parenId2) ) {
         //  $('#' + member.parenId2).append("<ul id='pr_" + member.parenId2 + "'><li id=" + member.memberId2 + ">" + member.nom + "</li></ul>")
         
           }
           else {
        //  $('#pr_' + member.parentId).append("<li id=" + member.memberId + ">" + member.otherInfo + "</li>")
           }


        }
      
    }
  //});
      $("#chart-container2").append({ container: $("#chart-container"), interactive: true, fade: true, speed: 'slow' });

    });

  </script>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.9/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.9/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script>
    $(function () {

      var oc = $('#chart-container').orgchart({
        'data': $('#chart-container2')
      });

    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div style="display: none">
    <ul id="chart-container2" class="clearfix"></ul>

  </div>
  <div id="chart-container">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```